# Google chrome and PHP, ERROR IN CHROMES PARSING?

Tags: php, parsing, google-chrome

I have this simple code in a php file...

```
<div id="main">
<?php 
     if {
     ....
     }
     else {
     ....
     }
?>

</div>
```

Now in mozilla, and IE it renders like this...

```
<div class="main">

<!-- HTML PARSED BY PHP -->

</div>
```

But in google chrome it renders like this.

```
<div id="main">

<!-- HTML PARSED BY PHP -->

div>
```

If I change the php file so that the php closing tag (?>) is like this after the ending curly bracket of the else statement like so...

```
}?>
```

Rather than....

```
}
?>
```

Then chrome renders the last div like so....

```
/div>
```

Is there an issue with chrome and php, and how can I stop it from happening. 
It is hard to validate any pages because of this weird issue.

Comment: Not the browsers renders the php, that's why it's called Preprocessing Hypertext. You html is sent to the browser and not the PHP.

Comment: So is this a wamp issue?? Why is this happening?

Comment: So how come it is different in browsers? If the same file gets sent, how come the outcome is different?

Comment: This should not be happening obviously, could it be something to do with the file is not being parsed correctly by your PHP processor?

Comment: PHP is not getting parsed; the result is invalid HTML. The broken result will be rendered differently across browsers.

Comment: I am using the latest wamp, I haven't tested this on an actual online server yet. Although, this does not affect the layout of my pages as I thought it would.

Comment: If you are using WAMP, maybe the file extension you are using is incorrect?

Comment: And how to fix it Pekka, thanks for you reply.

Comment: .php is surely the default for php files

Answer (score 0):

So, as I said, not the browser is the one who renders the PHP script, is your installation.
If the first line you should try to see what type of encoding your file has.

Change to `ANSI` if it differs.

Try to run your script on another installation/different machine.

Try an [Online Tool](http://writecodeonline.com/php/)